# jQuery Revolution Slider and Isotope plugins conflict

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've searched through this forum and, although there are quite a few questions / answers re. jQuery conflicts, I just can't sort out a solution to this.

I've hooked up 2 jQuery plugins to a HTML page - Isotope and Revolution Slider. Both work fine on their own, no problems, but when they are both installed on the same HTML document, Isotope shuts down completely.

My HTML code is as follows (sorry, there's a lot of it):

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-     scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>TECHNOCATS</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-test.css" media="all" />

<!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rs-css/responsive.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rs-plugin/css/settings.css"     media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="main">

    <div class="bannercontainer">

        <div class="banner">

            <ul>
             <li data-transition="random" data-slotamount="7" data-   link="http://www.google.de">
               <img src="rs-images/slides/marines-960.jpg">
               <div class="caption sft big_white"  data-x="100" data-y="100" data-speed="700" data-start="1700" data-easing="easeOutBack">Nunc tellus purus, auctor.</div>
               <div class="caption sfb big_orange"  data-x="100" data-y="142" data-speed="500" data-start="1900" data-easing="easeOutBack">Facilisis auctor id, tempor quis nulla.</div>
               <div class="caption lfr medium_grey"  data-x="100" data-y="210" data-speed="300" data-start="2000"> Sed et elementum tortor.</div>
             </li>
             <li data-transition="random" data-slotamount="7" data-link="http://www.google.de">
               <img src="rs-images/slides/legoman-tattoo-960.jpg">
               <div class="caption sft big_white"  data-x="400" data-y="100" data-speed="700" data-start="1700" data-easing="easeOutBack">Nunc tellus purus, auctor.</div>
               <div class="caption sfb big_orange"  data-x="400" data-y="142" data-speed="500" data-start="1900" data-easing="easeOutBack">Facilisis auctor id, tempor quis nulla.</div>
               <div class="caption lfr medium_grey"  data-x="510" data-y="210" data-speed="300" data-start="2000"> Sed et elementum tortor.</div>
             </li>

            </ul>
    </div> <!-- .banner -->

</div> <!-- .bannercontainer -->


<div style="width:100%; height:50px;"></div>

<div style="width:960px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
  <!-- Begin Portfolio -->
<div class="portfolio-wrapper">
    <ul class="filter">
      <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".ecommerce">eCommerce</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="items col4">

      <!-- Begin 1st Portfolio Item -->
      <li class="item web ecommerce" data-callback="callPortfolioScripts();"
              data-detailcontent='<div class="content">
                                          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                                                 <!-- Carousel items -->
                                                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                    <div class="active item">
                                                        <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/tcs-screen-1.jpg"><a href="style/images/art/ds1-1.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-1">
                                                        <span class="link"></span></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="item">
                                                        <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/tcs-screen-4.jpg"><a href="style/images/art/ds1-2.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-1">
                                                        <span class="link"></span></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="item">
                                                        <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/tcs-screen-3.jpg"><a href="style/images/art/ds1-3.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-1">
                                                        <span class="link"></span></a>
                                                    </div>
                                               </div>

                                              <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
                                              <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
                                              </div>

                                   </div>
                                   <div class="item-details">
                                       <h2>Town   &amp; Country Style</h2>

                                       <ul class="item-info">
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Date:</span>2012 - 2013</li>
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Technologies:</span> WordPress Theme Development, PHP, MySQL, jQuery, CSS, HTML</li>
                                        <li><span    class="lite1">Client:</span>Town &amp; Country Style</li>
                                      </ul>
                                       <p>Tonec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p> <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur occaecat cupidatat.</p>

                                      <a href="http://www.townandcountrystyle.com.au/" target="_blank" class="button">Launch Site</a>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="clear"></div>'
          > <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h3>Town &amp; Country Style</h3>
          <span class="meta">eCommerce Website, Custom WordPress Theme &amp; Blog</span> </div>
        <img src="images/tcs-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> </li>
      <!-- End 1st Portfolio Item --> 

      <!-- Begin 2nd Portfolio Item -->
      <li class="item web" data-callback="callPortfolioScripts();"
              data-detailcontent='<div class="content">
                                         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                                              <!-- Carousel items -->
                                              <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                    <div class="active item">
                                                        <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/art/ds2-1.jpg"><a href="style/images/tcs-screen-1.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-2">
                                                          <span class="link"></span></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="item">
                                                        <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/art/ds2-2.jpg"><a href="style/images/art/ds2-2.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-2">
                                                        <span class="link"></span></a>
                                                    </div>
                                               </div>

                                              <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
                                              <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
                                          </div>

                                   </div>
                                   <div class="item-details">
                                       <h2>K &amp; P Legal</h2>

                                       <ul class="item-info">
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Date:</span>2009 - 2012</li>
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Categories:</span> HTML, CSS, jQuery, Database Development</li>
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Client:</span> Sit Commodo Sollicitudin</li>
                                      </ul>
                                       <p>Tonec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p> <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur occaecat cupidatat.</p>

                                      <a href="#" class="button">Launch Site</a>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="clear"></div>'> <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h3>K&amp;P Legal</h3>
          <span class="meta">Website Development</span> </div>
        <img src="images/kplegal-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <!-- End 2nd Portfolio Item -->

      <!-- Begin 3rd Portfolio Item -->
      <li class="item web ecommerce" data-callback="callPortfolioScripts();"
               data-detailcontent='<div class="content">
                                            <div class="single"> <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/lullaby-1.jpg"><a href="style/images/art/ds3-1.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-3"><span class="link"></span></a></div>

                                       </div>
                                       <div class="item-details">
                                       <h2>Lullaby Linen</h2>
                                         <ul class="item-info">

                                        <li><span class="lite1">Date:</span>2010 - 2012</li>

                                      </ul>

                                       <p>As their business matured, Lullaby Linen outgrew their original site, built by Technocats in 2010.</p>

                                       <p>We are now involved in the redevelopment of the Lullaby Linen site, creating an online store with shopping cart. Expected completion date is June 2013.</p>

                                        <ul class="item-info">

                                        <li><span class="lite1">Technologies:</span>WordPress, HTML, CSS, jQuery, PHP, MySQL</li>

                                      </ul>

                                      <a href="#" class="button">New Site Coming Soon</a>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="clear"></div>'
              > <a href="#" >
        <div class="overlay">
          <h3>Lullaby Linen</h3>
          <span class="meta">Website Development</span> </div>
        <img src="images/lullaby-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <!-- End 3rd Portfolio Item --> 

      <!-- Begin 4th Portfolio Item -->
      <li class="item web ecommerce" data-callback="callPortfolioScripts();"
                 data-detailcontent='<div class="content">
                                              <div class="single"> <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/art/ds4-1.jpg"><a href="style/images/art/ds4-1.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-4"><span class="link"></span></a></div>

                                       </div>
                                       <div class="item-details">
                                       <h2>Wild!    </h2>

                                       <ul class="item-info">
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Date:</span>January 2013</li>
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Categories:</span>HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, PHP, MySQL</li>
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Client:</span> Sit Commodo Sollicitudin</li>
                                      </ul>
                                       <p>Tonec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p> <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur occaecat cupidatat.</p>

                                      <a href="http://eltoro-uk.com/" class="button">Launch Site</a>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="clear"></div>'
          > <a href="#" >
        <div class="overlay">
          <h3>Wild</h3>
          <span class="meta">eCommerce</span> </div>
        <img src="images/wild-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <!-- End 4th Portfolio Item --> 

      <!-- Begin 5th Portfolio Item -->
      <li class="item web" data-callback="callPortfolioScripts();"
                 data-detailcontent='<div class="content">
                                         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                                              <!-- Carousel items -->
                                              <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                    <div class="active item">
                                                        <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/art/ds5-1.jpg"><a href="style/images/art/ds5-1.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-5">
                                                        <span class="link"></span></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                        <div class="item">
                                                        <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/art/ds5-2.jpg"><a href="style/images/art/ds5-2.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-5">
                                                        <span class="link"></span></a>
                                                    </div>
                                               </div>

                                              <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
                                              <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
                                          </div>

                                   </div>
                                   <div class="item-details">
                                       <h2>Concept Concrete</h2>

                                       <ul class="item-info">
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Date:</span>2012</li>
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Categories:</span>HTML, CSS, jQuery, PHP, Development of Calculator app.</li>
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Client:</span> Sit Commodo Sollicitudin</li>
                                      </ul>
                                       <p>Tonec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p> <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur occaecat cupidatat.</p>

                                      <a href="#" class="button">Launch Site</a>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="clear"></div>'
          > <a href="#" >
        <div class="overlay">
          <h3>Concept Concrete</h3>
          <span class="meta">Website Development</span> </div>
        <img src="images/concept-concrete-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <!-- End 5th Portfolio Item --> 

      <!-- Begin 6th Portfolio Item -->
      <li class="item web" data-callback="callPortfolioScripts();"
                 data-detailcontent='<div class="content">
                                         <div class="single"> <img alt="" width="100%" src="style/images/art/ds6-1.jpg"><a href="style/images/art/ds6-1.jpg" class="fancybox-media" rel="item-6"><span class="link"></span></a></div>

                                   </div>
                                   <div class="item-details">
                                       <h2>Nurturing Hands</h2>

                                       <ul class="item-info">
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Date:</span>2011</li>
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Categories:</span>HTML, CSS</li>
                                        <li><span class="lite1">Client:</span> Sit Commodo Sollicitudin</li>
                                      </ul>
                                       <p>Tonec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p> <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur occaecat cupidatat.</p>

                                      <a href="#" class="button">Launch Site</a>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="clear"></div>'
          > <a href="#" >
        <div class="overlay">
          <h3>Nurturing Hands</h3>
          <span class="meta">Website Development</span> </div>
        <img src="images/nurturing-hands-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <!-- End 6th Portfolio Item --> 



            </ul>

        </div> <!-- End Portfolio -->

    </div>

   </div> <!-- main -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The init.js file (referenced at the end of the HTML) is as follows:

```
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------     */
 /* REVOLUTION SLIDER
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

 var tpj=jQuery;
 tpj.noConflict();

 tpj(document).ready(function() {

 if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
 tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;

tpj('.banner').revolution(
    {
        delay:6000,
        startwidth:960,
        startheight:500,

        onHoverStop:"on",                       

        thumbWidth:100,                         
        thumbHeight:50,
        thumbAmount:3,

        hideThumbs:0,
        navigationType:"none",              
        navigationArrows:"none",                

        navigationStyle:"round",                


        navigationHAlign:"left",                
        navigationVAlign:"bottom",                  
        navigationHOffset:30,
        navigationVOffset:30,

        soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
        soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
        soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
        soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,

        soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
        soloArrowRightValign:"center",
        soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
        soloArrowRightVOffset:0,

        touchenabled:"on",                      


        stopAtSlide:-1,                         
        stopAfterLoops:-1,                      
        hideCaptionAtLimit:0,                   
        hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,               
        hideSliderAtLimit:0,                    


        fullWidth:"on",

        shadow:0                                

    });

 });

 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 /* ISOTOPE PORTFOLIO
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var $container = $('.portfolio-wrapper .items');
     $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });
   });

   $('.filter li a').click(function () {

    $('.filter li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });

    return false;
    });
 });
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Mekong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: **Revoltion Slider** No changes.

2: **ISOTOP**  you should use noconflit variable. in my exemple i'm using abc

```
var abc=jQuery;
abc.noConflict();
abc(document).ready(function () {
var $container = abc('.portfolio-wrapper .items');
 $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
});
abc('.filter li a').click(function () {

abc('.filter li a').removeClass('active');
abc(this).addClass('active');

var selector = abc(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({
    filter: selector
});

return false;
});
});
```

Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to modify your init.js, You may get your answer
       /*---------------------------------------       */
          /* REVOLUTION SLIDER
         /*------------------------------------------------*/

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if (jQuery.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
    jQuery.fn.css = jQuery.fn.cssOriginal;
    jQuery('.banner').revolution({
        delay:6000,
        startwidth:960,
        startheight:500,
        onHoverStop:"on",                   
        thumbWidth:100,                         
        thumbHeight:50,
        thumbAmount:3,
        hideThumbs:0,
        navigationType:"none",              
        navigationArrows:"none",            
        navigationStyle:"round",                
        navigationHAlign:"left",                
        navigationVAlign:"bottom",                  
        navigationHOffset:30,
        navigationVOffset:30,
        soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
        soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
        soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
        soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,
        soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
        soloArrowRightValign:"center",
        soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
        soloArrowRightVOffset:0,
        touchenabled:"on",                      
        stopAtSlide:-1,                         
        stopAfterLoops:-1,                      
        hideCaptionAtLimit:0,                   
        hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,               
        hideSliderAtLimit:0,                    
        fullWidth:"on",
        shadow:0                                
      });

    });

/*--------------------------------------------*/
  /* ISOTOPE PORTFOLIO
  /*---------------------------------------  */
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     var $container = jQuery('.portfolio-wrapper .items');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
     });
   });
   jQuery('.filter li a').click(function () {
   jQuery('.filter li a').removeClass('active');
   jQuery(this).addClass('active');

   var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
      $container.isotope({
      filter: selector
    });
  return false;
   });
 });
        /*----------------------------------------------------  */
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone gets to this question looking for the solution to an error provoked by Revolution Slider which resets the filter on an Isotope gallery after every new slide.

I received this error from a page made for wordpress.

I got these two plugins working making the selector var a global one and applying it to the filter on isotope relayout...

The lines where changed in pl.masonic.js. Line numbers are aproximations.

- Added `var selector = "";` at the beginning of the file.
- Line 37: Removing the var from the line `var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter')`. So it became `selector = $(this).attr('data-filter')`
- Line 85: converted `filter: '*'` to `filter: selector`